# The "Network Map" function in Windows 7 does not work for me. Why?

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking

When I attempt to use the `See Full Map` function in Windows 7 `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center` it always abends.

I really have no idea what the problem may be. I am sure this Windows network topology map function worked when I was using the Win 7 pre-release. However, now that I am using the retail RTM version of Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit) I can no longer create a Network Map. My best guess from the (so-called) "help" provided is that a "device" (my router?) is incompatible with Microsoft's [Link Layer Topology Discovery (LLTD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Topology_Discovery) protocol.

Below is a text diagram of my LAN. The error occurs even when the only system connected to the DIR-655 is my Win 7 desktop. This is why I suspect the DIR-655. But what could be wrong??

If a setting in my router is preventing LLTD from working I have no idea which it might be. Was hoping I might get a suggestion on what to start looking at.

```
                                Type of Connection
                                 [] coax
    ( Internet )                 | wired ethernet
      ( ISP )                    : wireless ethernet
         []
      [Motorola SB5100 "Surfboard" cable modem]
          |  WAN
     =====================================================
    + D-Link DIR-655 router, firmware v1.34NA, 2010/04/16 +
     =====================================================
       |    LAN             |                   :
       |                    |                 Wi-Fi
       |                    |                   :
    [Win 7 64-bit] [Seagate Dockstar] [MacBook OS X 10.6.4]
```

---

**Update:**

I've tried resetting the DIR-655 to factory defaults, rebooting Windows, then trying to map my network. It failed in the same way. But at least now I have some confidence the problem is not a result of anything (obvious) which I did to the configuration.

**Update:**

For what's it's worth, this function works again. I do no know when it started working again. I do not know why it is working. But it is working now.

Is there a way to close a question as "No longer any point in pursuing?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a firmware update? Latest firmware is 1.34NA, dated 5-20-2010

That model supports LLTD
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/windowsvista/bowman_hardware.mspx

Also see this, problems with LLTD when using MAC filtering
http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21605901-LLTD-on-a-DIR655-router

Comment: thanks for the LLTD assurance link :-). I thought it should work but it never hurts to have that confirmed. The firmware dated 5-20-2010 is the same as what I have installed. D-Link apparently used the date of the zip file on the web site. The firmware file inside the zip, DIR655A4_FW134NAb03.bin, is dated 2010/04/16. Maybe they gave it a month of beta testing?

Comment: "Maybe they gave it a month of beta testing?"

One would hope this is the reason, I hate it when softwware/hardware companies use their customers as beta testers on non beta products.